# Switch toggle enabling and disabling

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a switch in such a way that all that when it is enabled everything works fine but when the switch is toggled to disabled, no links work on the webpage or no data is clickable.

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.4.0/css/bootstrap4-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.4.0/js/bootstrap4-toggle.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="fetchAndDisplayData()">Click me</button>
<input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-size="sm">
                      <table id="id01" class='table table-bordered table-striped'>
                        <tbody>
                        <thead>

                          <tr>
                            <th>Title </th>
                       <th>Description </th>
                            </tr>
                    </thead>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
-----------------------------------------------------------------

<script>
  function fetchAndDisplayData() {
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://localhost:8888/api/get/read1.php";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        myFunction(myArr);
    }

};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
  function myFunction(arr) {
      var out = "";
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          out += '<tr><td><a href="' + arr[i].link + '">' +
              arr[i].title + '</a></td>';
          out += '<td>' + arr[i].description + '<br></td>';

          out += '<td><a href="' + arr[i].link + '">' +
              arr[i].link + '</a></td></tr>';
}
      fetchAndDisplayData();
        </script>

        <script>
        $(window).scroll(function() {
    var height = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (height > 70) {
        $('#Arrow').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('#Arrow').fadeOut();
    }
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Arrow").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
        return false;
    });

});
</script>
</body>
```

How can I achieve this? I tried checking but so many functions are confusing me . I am new to Javascript. Ps. all tags are closed properly, couldn't post the whole code.

Comment: What do you mean 'click twice' - it is click/pause/click or a double click?

Comment: 1st click: display contents in the table
2nd click: disable the contents in the table
3rd click: enable the contents
4th click: roll back the contents

Comment: Well that's not a very user-friendly (or intuitive) interface but hey... What you are going to have to do is keep a track of the number of clicks that has been for the button then perform the required actions.

Comment: Hi Jeff, you are right. So instead I am thinking of creating a switch so when I click it ON, everything on the page should be enabled and free to access whereas when I disable(off) it should not let me click on any links. @jeff How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to need something like (note this is only a sample because you have not provided any html code that has this button on it - apart from loading the data).

```
var clickCounter = 0;
function btnClick() {
   clickCounter++;
   if( clickCounter > 3 ) clickCounter = 0;
   switch( clickCounter ) {
     case 0 : break; // do display action here
     case 1 : break; // do hide action here
     case 2 : break; // do enable action here
     case 3 : break; // do rollback action here
   }
}
```